# How to express argument of type QVariantMap in qdbus command line tool

Tags: qt5, qdbus

I'm trying to use the following command :

```bash
qdbus org.kde.krunner /org/kde/krunner org.kde.KDBusService.CommandLine
```

The signature is the following :

```bash
org.kde.KDBusService.CommandLine                -- int(QStringList arguments, QString working-dir, QVariantMap platform-data)
```

But I received the following error, and I don't know why :

```bash
qdbus org.kde.krunner /org/kde/krunner org.kde.KDBusService.CommandLine "ls" "/" "{}"
Sorry, can't pass arg of type 'QVariantMap'.
```

What can I do for casting the right format ?